# List like card with buttons

Tags: android, listview

How can I do list like this?What must I use?I have string-array,can I put that in this card?[image]

Comment: You can add.Why not?

Comment: Always use documentation(http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/material/lists-cards.html) before asking here, if you can't find solution there you can ask in SO

Answer (score 1):

You can get the string by:
`String[] mydata = getResources.getStringArray(R.array.mystrings);`
Then you can pass it to the constructor of the adapter class and use it there.